# Can I say "They usually go bowling on Saturday and Sundays"?

Tags: grammar

I'm stuck with this prbolem:
Can I say "They usually go bowling on Saturday and Sundays"?
It's the correct answer of a test I had.

I wonder why isn't it "They usually go bowling on Saturdays and Sundays".

Many thanks!

Comment: "... on Saturdays and Sundays" is fine. "... on Saturday and Sunday" is also fine but *might* suggest they go away for the whole weekend, rather than going each day. Mixing the singular and the plural is not idiomatic.

Comment: If that (seriously non-idiomatic) combination of singular ***Saturday*** with plural ***Sundays*** was accurately transcribed as being the "correct answer of a test", ***don't do any more tests from that source***. It's complete garbage!

Comment: Thank you, guys. I can't agree more. I now have the courage to stand against it:)